# Android and Kotlin: Unresolved reference: home

Tags: android, kotlin

I have activity with up home navigation button.
There is my listener:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            onBackPressed()
            true
        }
    else -> false
}
```

When i build this i get the error: Unresolved reference: home

Comment: what is your minSdk

Comment: compileSdkVersion - 26;
minSdkVersion - 19

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can put this line in onCreate()

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

And then in your manifest add a meta-data tag like below.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="Your Activity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.app_name.YourActivity" />
  </activity>
```

If you do this you  do not need to handle home button press in onOptionsItemSelected() method.